spring cloud config complex multiple folders
I am trying to integrate multiple microservices and custom filenanes, and keep porperties in a separate repo. It is loading propes only from root folder, How do I load properties from subfolders and also with custom names?
My folder structure looks like this,
properties-repo
 |_A
    |_
      B
       |_DEV
            |_db.properties
            |_stp.properties
 |_Common
        |_X
          |_shared.properties
           

My Server Config bootstrap is,
server.port=8888
spring.application.name=config-server
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/props-repo 
spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths=A,B,DEV,X
spring.cloud.config.server.git.cloneStart=true
management.security.enabled=false

And my Client Config bootstrap is,
spring.application.name:client-config
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.name=${spring.application.name},shared,db,stp

